# error C2101: '&' on constant

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dictionary, reference, assign

I have a following code:

```
std::map<size_t,Cell&> m_cellMap;
```

when Cell is defined as follows:

```
class Cell
    {
      public:
        Cell(int x = 0,int y = 0) : m_x(x),m_y(y) { }
      private:
        int m_x;
        int m_y;
        /// class members and methods
    };
```

I can`t compile below code:

```
Cell c;
m_cellMap[0] = c;
```

Getting the error : `error C2101: '&' on constant`
What is wrong ?How can it be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: References aren't default constructible or assignable. These operations are required for the mapped_type in the operation you show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible to hold references in standard containers, use pointers instead:

```
std::map<size_t,Cell*> m_cellMap;

Cell c;
m_cellMap[0] = &c;
```

Comment: Jinx! :-) Is there a way to see our timestamps closer than to the second?

Comment: @Yakk: Wow! ... I don't know how to see the timestamps any more precisely, but when I order by `oldest`, you appear above me.

Comment: Be careful that `c` does not go out of scope.  In that case, the pointer in `m_cellMap` is going to point to garbage.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot make a `std::map` to references.  A reference doesn't have the properties that a value that a `std::map` maps to must have.

Try creating a `std::map<size_t, Cell*>`, and doing `m_cellMap[0] = &c;`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to deal with raw pointers (and you really don't want to), then you can use `std::reference_wrapper` instead.

```
std::map<size_t,std::reference_wrapper<Cell>> m_cellMap;
```

If you do that, then you need to avoid using the `[]` operator.

Do the following to insert into the map.

```
m_cellMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, c));
```

If you use pointers instead of references, then you need to manage the lifetime of the `Cell` object that you create.

Comment: I don't see any difference between this and a raw pointer. Both imply that something else is managing the lifetimes of the referenced objects.

Comment: The difference being that with the raw pointer, you are responsible for deleting the pointer when you are done with it.  Using `reference_wrapper`, the object will exist as long as you need it to and will be cleaned up automatically.

Comment: But I guess that is not correct with reference_wrapper.  I am confusing that with the functionality of shared_ptr.  With reference_wrapper, the lifetime of the object is still dependent upon the scope in which the object was created.